# Error : Array {-6, 2} has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list

Tags: graphics, scripting, education

I'm trying to plot two lines and the point of intersection between them,
and I got this error :

```
Coordinate index -3 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex.
Coordinate index 3 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex.
Array {-6, 2} has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list.
Array {4, 4} has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list.
```

Here is the code :

```
LineIntersectionPoint[{a_, b_}, {c_, 
    d_}] := (Det[{a, b}] (c - d) - Det[{c, d}] (a - b))/
   Det[{a - b, c - d}];

Manipulate[DynamicModule[{Q},
  
  Q = LineIntersectionPoint[{A, B}, {C0, D0}];
  {Graphics[{
     {Black, Line[A, B]},
     {Black, Line[C0, D0]},
     Purple, PointSize[0.04], Point[Q],
     {Red, Arrow[A, B]},
     {Blue, Arrow[C0, D0]}}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large
    ]}
  ],
 {{A, {-6, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{B, {-3, 1}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{C0, {4, 4}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{D0, {3, 3}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator}
 ]
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Syntax errors: the arguments of `Line` and `Arrow` should be enclosed in a list, so `Line[A, B]` should be `Line[{A, B}]` and similarly for all others. Not sure that this is intended, but your Line and Arrow objects are exactly coincident, so you will never see the Line. If you want an extended line that goes through A and B, use `InfiniteLine` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! I did not notice

Answer (score 2):

In case you want the lines to extend across the plot:

```
ClearAll[LineIntersectionPoint]
LineIntersectionPoint[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := (Det[{a, b}] (c - d) - Det[{c, d}] (a - b))/Det[{a - b, c - d}];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   {Black, InfiniteLine[{A, B}]}, {Black, InfiniteLine[{C0, D0}]},
   {Purple, PointSize[0.04], Point[LineIntersectionPoint[{A, B}, {C0, D0}]]},
   {Red, Arrow[{A, B}]}, {Blue, Arrow[{C0, D0}]}
  },
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Large
 ],
 {{A, {-6, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{B, {-3, 1}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{C0, {4, 4}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{D0, {3, 3}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator}
]
```

[image: modified output with InfiniteLine]